# Mpandroichart (Horizontal chart) set each bar a different color

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

Im trying to change the horizontal bar color if the yValue is negative then the bar should be red and if not it will be the default one.

I have gone to

```
 bardataset.setColor(Color.RED);    

 set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
```

but this is also not the one im looking.

I want to set a bar color based on the yValue , but the above code will set all the data set to color red and

```
set1.setColor(colorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
```

is some what a random color for the bar.how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately setting colors based on the value is **not yet possible**.

I am working on including such a feature in the future.

Comment: Thank you Philipp Jahoda im hoping for this in the future :)

Comment: Hello, face same problem here. I used List<int> color to set color for each bar component, but when set this color for list of view background, it return wrong color?